# Why should MAP be invariant under reparameterization?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, bayesian, posterior, map-estimation

I learned why MAP suffers from being reparametrization invariance while MLE not from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2781058/351322), but I don't know why reparametrization invariance even matters? What is the non-linear mapping concretely and why we do the non-linear mapping depicted below?

I wonder if I am wrong: After we obtain the posterior we can provide a point estimate summary, such as mean, median, and mode [if necessary](https://statswithr.github.io/book/losses-and-decision-making.html). In which scenarios do we apply non-linear mapping to the posterior? For the sake of what?

[image]

I learned from this section in [this book](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book0.html) that:

> We will now show that different parameterizations can pick different points in this interval arbitrarily.
> [image]

But it is unclear why we apply the parameterization to the MAP.
Any materials(tutorials) would also be very appreciated.

Comment: This lack of invariance shows that the MAP is not a stable estimator. When considering the estimated density $f(\cdot|\theta)$ relying on the plugged-in MAP, this estimated density will vary according to the choice of parameterisation.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks, professor. Could you please refer me to some materials on the `plugged-in MAP`?

Answer (score 6):

If $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,1)$ and $\mu\sim\mathcal N(0,10)$, the MAP of $\theta$ is
$$\theta^\text{MAP}(x)=\dfrac{10}{11}x$$while the MAP of $\alpha=\alpha(\theta)=\exp\{\theta\}$ is
$$\alpha^\text{MAP}(x)=\exp\left\{\dfrac{10}{11}x-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{11}}\right\}$$
The plot of the plugged-in density estimates $\varphi(\cdot;\theta^\text{MAP}(x),1)$ versus $\varphi(\cdot;\log\{\alpha^\text{MAP}(x)\})$ shows a clear difference between these two densities.

[image]

However the distinction decreases with the sample size increasing.

Comment: I think I have got the idea of the plugged-in MAP, but I still wonder when we need to do the plugged-in MAP? And for what purpose? I mean, I know that we provide a mean or mode of a posterior distribution for the purpose of summarizing the posterior using just one number. Then why the plugged-in MAP?

Comment: You should expand on the reasons you want a point estimate and on its ultimate purpose...

Comment: I learned from [here](https://statswithr.github.io/book/losses-and-decision-making.html) that it can be used for decision making.